# Problems with the date 20 October in some years

Tags: javascript, date

I wrote some code in Javascript that was working without any problem.
But when I put the date `October 20, 2013`, I was returned the date `October 19, 2013`.

The same applies to the years `2019`, `2024` and `2030` (*not tested 
previous years and not later*).
This problem shows up in all browsers I test (*Google Chrome*, *Internet Explorer*, *Mozilla Firefox*, *Opera* and *Safari*).

When I write:

```
date = new Date("10/20/2013");
document.write(date);
```

The result I get is:

> Sat Oct 19 2013 23:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)

Someone could tell me why this is happening and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Works fine for me in newest Chrome, outputs Oct 20, as expected? -> [***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/H9UJY/)

Comment: Maybe it's your timezone...

Comment: Here also working normally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

October 20th, 2013 is the cutover for BRST.  So if you are in Brazil (in a BRST timezone) you will transition from BRT (UTC -3) to BRST (UTC-2).

From [TimeAndDate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/sa/brst.html):

> Current time in São Paulo: Wednesday, May 22, 2013 at 3:19:14 PM BRT
>
> São Paulo will stay on BRT until Sunday, October 20, 2013 going to
>   BRST

The transition happens at Midnight and Midnight to 1am is skipped. To guarantee a time on that date you can try:

```
date = new Date("10/20/2013 01:00:00");
```

And you should get `10/20/2013 01:00:00` with BRST as the timezone designation.

For someone in a US timezone that participates in DST who wants to see this issue; Use the US daylight savings time transition point of March 10th 2013, where 2am is skipped ahead to 3am:

```
var d = new Date("03/10/2013 02:59:59")
alert(d);   // Returns 1:59:59 AM in the Standard Time Zone

var d = new Date("03/10/2013 03:00:00")
alert(d);   // Returns 3:00:00 AM in the Daylight Time Zone
```

Comment: More information about JS issues with dates that have time changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839244/why-is-safari-confused-about-date-getday-for-dst-start-in-sydney-aus-time-zon

Comment: Which explains why only on certain years, i.e when the date falls on a Sunday! Good catch John.

Comment: Great! Google Chrome return your Date to 1 hour but Safari mantains changing to BRST.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers may show incorrect values when using Date.parse (which is the same as 'new Date(string)'). I don't know the reason, but the best way of creating a date is using the 
[Date(year, month, day) constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Example:

```
console.log(new Date(2013, 10, 20))
```